# How to try to invite friends on Facebook Instant Game SDK? (ShareAsync not working)

Tags: facebook-instant-games

I want to know how to invite or request. but FBInstant SDK doesn't ask me any target IDs when sharing.

my code is following (Typescript),

```
const options : FBInstant.SharePayload = {
    intent  : "INVITE",
    text    : "SomeText",
    image   : base64Image, // exist.
    data    : {}
};
FBInstant.shareAsync(options);
```

and this shows "SHARE" window. FBInstant.shareAsync() not work exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should actually use `FBInstant.context.chooseAsync`/`FBInstant.context.createAsync` for invites in Instant Games. Your goal should be to move the players you want to play together into the same context (as specified by `FBInstant.context` methods).

Sharing (`shareAsync`) is intended for broadcast sharing and despite the `intent` parameter, it is not that useful for invitations.

Comment: I used all of "INTENT". but It always shows "SHARE" state. I'm confuse about this parameter.

Comment: The `intent` parameter doesn't do anything, that's why you're confused.